# DOM based xss issue on setting top.location=self.location

Tags: angularjs, xss, fortify

I am using a clickjacking prevention code:

```
<style id="antiClickjack">

body{display:none !important;}  

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">   

if (self === top)    {
    var antiClickjack=document.getElementById("antiClickjack");  
    antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);

} else {
    top.location = self.location;
} 

</script>
```

In scanning through fortify the below mentioned line shows DOM based xss issue:

```
top.location = self.location;
```

Please suggest some way of fixing this...

Comment: You should format your questions more clearly, using the format code feature and separating code from plain text. You should also provide more background on what is happening. Like what exactly is not working, or what your expected behaviour is, what exactly you are trying to accomplish and what you did before this code that is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
top.location = encodeURI(self.location);
```